# How to send an email with attachment which is derived from reading my email

Tags: node.js, imap, sendmail, attachment, nodemailer

Suppose I extracted an attachment(PDF) from my email, and now want to send the same attachment to a different email.

**This is the derived attachment using IMAP.**

```
[ { type: 'attachment',
    **content:
     <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 34 0d 0a 25 e2 e3 cf d3 0d 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0d 0a 3c 3c 0d 0a 2f 54 79 70 65 20 2f 50 61 67 65 0d 0a 2f 4d 65 64 69 61 42 ... >**,
    contentType: 'application/pdf',
    partId: '2',
    release: null,
    contentDisposition: 'attachment',
    **filename: 'Madhav-Result.pdf',**
    contentId: '<f_ks78pexx0>',
    cid: 'f_ks78pexx0',
    headers:
     Map {
       'content-type' => [Object],
       'content-disposition' => [Object],
       'content-transfer-encoding' => 'base64',
       'content-id' => '<f_ks78pexx0>',
       'x-attachment-id' => 'f_ks78pexx0' },
    checksum: '796c263199fb2c432f335abc59326080',
    size: 388167 } ]
```

**Extracted content, filename from attachments.**

**Sending Mail**

```
var mail = {
    from: "sender@gmail.com",
    to: "reciever@gmail.com",
    subject: "Sending Email using Node.js",
    text: "That was easy!",
    attachments: [
        {
            filename: fname, 
            content: cntnt
       }
   ]
  };
```

**Able to send the mail successfully, but unable to open the attachment received. (Also it's  doc not in PDF which is expected)**

Comment: You'll probably want to set the content type on the attachment when you send.

Comment: @arnt, As I was getting the content of attachment in <Buffer .........>, so I simply performed 

`fs.writeFileSync('Madhav-Result.pdf',fileContent);` -> Generated pdf file.

Stored the location and updated my attachments as

` attachments: [
                        {
                            filename: attachedFile,
                            path:filePath,
                       }
                   ]`

And then unlinked the file created.


This now sends the file in attachment as PDF which I read from my email.

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: I expect reading it from a file triggered type sniffing based on either the contents or the name of the file, which added `contentType: "application/pdf"` to your attachments array in an implicit, roundabout way. It's a tiny bit like the joke... "Q: how do you centre something on a web site? A: you crawl a million web sites and use them to train an ML system, and it emits the right CSS clause."